# Extending fluent interface

Tags: java, fluent-interface, fest

I'm starting using [Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x) and I like it a lot, but wonder if it's possible to extend the existing tests in a general way like this:

- add method `hasSizeAtLeast(int limit)` in `GroupAssert`
- add method `startsWithIgnoringCase(String prefix)` in `StringAssert`
- use alternatives like `x.either().isIn(someSet).or().isNull()`

These are just examples what I could need soon. I can do some workaround for each of them, but then I lose the readability and the easy of use of the fluent interface.

My last example is meant to throw iff both `x.isIn(someSet)` and `x.isNull()` do.

Comment: I would understand **either ... or ...** as a XOR connection, i.e. it should throw off iff exactly one of them throws. (But I'm not a native english speaker.)

Comment: Neither am I, but I think you're not exactly right. AFAIK, "either-or" may be also used when you want to stress the existence of the choice. Also `hamcrest` uses it this way.

Comment: Link to fluent assertions is 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [a post](http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=257) by the author about opening up his API for extending assertions on already handled types. Lesson #1 in particular discusses the change to un-finalize classes. The post also gives an example of sub-classing `StringAssert` as `MyStringAssert`.

However, it looks like you cannot extend classes such as `StringAssert` in a way that maintains the "fluency" of the API. The `StringAssert` class isn't final, but still it doesn't allow you to parameterize its type (i.e. the "this" type that's returned by methods in `StringAssert` itself) in subclasses. For example, let's say you add a method `checkFoo` in `MyStringAssert`. As you discovered, the following is invalid because the original `StringAssert` methods return `StringAssert`:

```
new MyStringAssert("abcd").contains("a").checkFoo(); // compile-time error!
```

You only can call your subclass's methods first, which is valid but kind of lame:

```
new MyStringAssert("abcd").checkFoo().contains("a"); // compiles
```

You might consider contacting the author, or even submitting a patch to his git project. A possible solution would be to add the parameterized type back into `StringAssert`, and also provide the `StringAssert` concrete type via an anonymous subclass within `Assertions.assertThat(String)`, which is the recommended entry point anyway. Then, everybody else can subclass `StringAssert` as you described. I haven't tested this suggestion either, but it seems to make sense...

Comment: Thank you. The link actually shows, that extending `StringAssert` does NOT really work, since you can't return `MyStringAssert`. So you can't get `new MyStringAssert("abcd").contains("a").hasSizeAtLeast(3);` working using inheritance.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Apologies for the confusion, I should have tried this first! I will my response to remove the misinformation and provide a few suggestions.

Comment: No problem, you've helped me a lot as I was being completely clueless about where to start. I'm quite sure your suggestion makes sense. It's a pity, Java provides only such a terrible workaround for [self-types](http://www.jroller.com/scolebourne/entry/java_7_self_types) forcing everybody to either pollute the code with otherwise useless generic parameter or to lose flexibility.